# Confusion with Queryset.annotate()

Tags: django, django-orm

I have two models:

```
class Property(models.Model):
    # code here...

class AccommodationType(models.Model):
    property = models.ForeignKey(Property, related_name='accommodation_types')
    # rest of code here...
```

What I'm trying to to is to annotate Property's queryset with count of related AccommodationType's and filter it by the value of this count. So here is my code:

```
qs = Property.objects.all()
qs.annotate(acc_types_count=Count('accommodation_types'))
filtered = qs.filter(acc_types_count=1)
```

and here I got the error:

```
django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'acc_types_count' into field. Choices are:  # ...rest of the fields
```

Where I am wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`annotate`, like `filter`, doesn't mutate the queryset but returns a new one. You need to reassign that to `qs`:

```
qs.annotate(acc_types_count=Count('accommodation_types'))
```

Or combine it with the original query:

```
qs = Property.objects.all().annotate(acc_types_count=Count('accommodation_types'))
```